# PHP/MYSQL Working with data base and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck trying to make to work the below piece of code its seems that something in my syntax is not properly declared i tried to change the name of the variables but still doesn't work, I have a table in my database called packages, any ideas of what the error could be? please :( :

```
  <?PHP

    include('connection.php');
    include('validation.php');
    include('header.php');

    $PID = $_GET['PID'];
    $q_getpackage = "SELECT * FROM packages WHERE PID=$PID";
    $r_getpackage = mysql_query($q_getpackage,$connection);



    ?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Numans' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>

    <title>Products Information</title>
</head>
<body>



      <div class="packages_wraper"><!--Packages Wraper-->       

      <div class="package_name"><?php echo mysql_result($r_getpackage,0,'name');?></h3>
        <div class="details"><?php echo mysql_result($r_getpackage,0,'details');?</div>
    <div><?php echo mysql_result($r_getpackage,0,'guide');?> </div>
    <div><?php echo mysql_result($r_getpackage,0,'review');?> </div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="<?php echo mysql_result($r_getpackage,0,'pic_url');?>"/></div>

        </div><!--END Packages Wraper--> 

     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an error that says:

```
Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/tk1/domains/valbet.tk/public_html/product_info.php on line 33
Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/tk1/domains/valbet.tk/public_html/product_info.php on line 34
Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/tk1/domains/valbet.tk/public_html/product_info.php on line 35
Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/tk1/domains/valbet.tk/public_html/product_info.php on line 36
```

Comment: try `0 1 2 3` instead of `'name', 'details', 'guide' and 'review'`. Btw this will show only the first result of the query

Answer (score -1):

The SQL statement didn't execute properly. Run `echo mysql_error()` after the `mysql_query()` to see why not, examine the output, and fix whatever it tells you.

(Also, take the standard warnings about input validation/prepared statements/mysqli as given)

Comment: what's the problem? If the output is that it isn't a valid result resource, that's because there was an error with the mysql_query.